# Edit question with pending edits but can't accept edit

Tags: discussion, tags, review, suggested-edits

I want to edit (retag) a question with an edit pending. Normally, I would just review/accept/improve the pending edit, but I've already hit my review limit for the next couple of hours. Is there any way to still get around the pending edit, or do I just have to wait until somebody else reviews the edit?

Comment: you gotta wait.